# Proof explanation of $\prod_{k=2}^n \big(1- \frac{2}{k(k+1)} \big) = \frac{1}{3} \big(1+\frac{2}{n} \big), n \geq 2$

Tags: analysis, induction, proof-explanation

I want to understand the proof of

$$\prod_{k=2}^n \big(1- \frac{2}{k(k+1)} \big) = \frac{1}{3} \big(1+\frac{2}{n} \big), n \geq 2$$

via induction.

$$\text{Base case: } n=2 \Rightarrow\prod_{k=2}^2\big(1-\frac{2}{k(k+1)}\big) = 1-\frac{2}{2(2+1)} = \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3} \big(1+\frac{2}{2}\big)$$

$$\text{Hypothesis: The proposition holds for an } n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ with } n \ge 2$$

$$\text{Induction step: } \prod_{k=2}^{n+1} \big(1- \frac{2}{k(k+1)} \big) = \big(1- \frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)} \big) \cdot \prod_{k=2}^n \big( 1- \frac{2}{k(k+1)} \big)$$

$$= \text{IH: } \big( 1- \frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)} \big) \cdot \frac{1}{3} \big(1+ \frac{2}{n}\big) $$

$$= \frac{(n+1)(n+2)-2}{(n+1)(n+2)} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{n+2}{n} = \frac{1}{3} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)-2}{n(n+1)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{3} \frac{n^2+3n+2-2}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{n+3}{n+1 }= \frac{1}{3}\cdot \big(\frac{n+1}{n+1} +\frac{2}{n+1}\big)$$

$$=\frac{1}{3} \big(1+\frac{2}{n+1} \big)$$

What I don't understand are the two steps:

What's been done to remove the $1-$ and $1+$?:

$$= \frac{(n+1)(n+2)-2}{(n+1)(n+2)} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{n+2}{n} = \frac{1}{3} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)-2}{n(n+1)}$$

How do we get the $\frac{1}{3}\cdot \big(\frac{n+1}{n+1} +\frac{2}{n+1}\big)$ here?:

$$=\frac{1}{3} \frac{n^2+3n+2-2}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{n+3}{n+1 }= \frac{1}{3}\cdot \big(\frac{n+1}{n+1} +\frac{2}{n+1}\big)$$

Comment: As a note, induction isn't really that needed, since $1-\frac2{k(k+1)}=\frac{(k-1)(k+2)}{k(k+1)}$ makes it (somewhat obviously) telescoping. Regardless, rewriting it as such will also make the induction proof easier as well.

Comment: Just basic fractions manipulations : $1=\dfrac{n+1}{n+1}$, for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first step we are using the induction hypotesis that is

$$\prod_{k=2}^n \left(1- \frac{2}{k(k+1)} \right) = \frac{1}{3} \left(1+\frac{2}{n} \right)$$

the second one is

$$= \frac{(n+1)(n+2)-2}{(n+1)\color{red}{(n+2)}} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{\color{red}{n+2}}{n} = \frac{1}{3} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)-2}{n(n+1)}$$

and finally

$$=\frac{1}{3} \frac{n^2+3n+2-2}{n(n+1)} =\frac{1}{3} \frac{n(n+3)}{n(n+1)}= \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{n+3}{n+1 }=$$$$= \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{n+1+2}{n+1 }= \frac{1}{3}\cdot \left(\frac{n+1}{n+1} +\frac{2}{n+1}\right)$$